# How do the Gauss-Markov Assumptions relate to the OLS Properties?

Tags: regression, least-squares

How do the 5 Gauss-Markov Assumptions below relate to the OLS properties of Biasedness, Consistency and Efficiency if they are violated?

[image]

Comment: did you search for answer on this site already?

Comment: There is no consistent answer on all 5 assumptions.